# Issue with time variable conflict in OpenGL 4.3 program Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Tags: c++, c, opengl, opengl-es, glut

So I am getting a strange error when compiling an OpenGL 4.3 program and was hoping someone could help. I have been working on one of the recipes in the OpenGL Development Cookbook for a RippleDeformer. I am running into a compile error and am not sure how to fix it.

It seems like there is a variable in the main.cpp program named `time` and also one of the OpenGL libraries also involves the `time.h` header, so that causes a problem with the declaration. I tried to change the name of the variable in the program and it compiles, but it gives me a different error when I run the executable.

I tried to compile using the following commands:

```
g++ -o mycc main.cpp GLSLShader.cpp -lglut -lGLEW -lGL -lm -lglm
```

So let me give you the message and then the actual main.cpp and shader program:

#### Error Message

```
    ^
main.cpp: At global scope:
main.cpp:62:7: error: ‘float time’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
float time = 0;
      ^
In file included from /usr/include/pthread.h:24:0,
             from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits/gthr-default.h:35,
             from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits/gthr.h:148,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ext/atomicity.h:35,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h:39,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:42,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
             from main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/time.h:192:15: error: previous declaration of ‘time_t time(time_t*)’
extern time_t time (time_t *__timer) __THROW;
          ^
main.cpp: In function ‘void OnRender()’:
main.cpp:198:7: error: assignment of function ‘time_t time(time_t*)’
time = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME)/1000.0f * SPEED;
     ^
main.cpp:198:7: error: cannot convert ‘float’ to ‘time_t(time_t*)throw () {aka long int(long int*)throw     
()}’ in assignment
main.cpp:213:35: error: cannot convert ‘time_t (*)(time_t*)throw () {aka long int (*)(long int*)throw ()}’ to ‘GLfloat {aka float}’ in argument passing
glUniform1f(shader("time"), time);
                               ^
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include "GLSLShader.h"

#define GL_CHECK_ERRORS assert(glGetError()== GL_NO_ERROR);

#ifdef _DEBUG 
#pragma comment(lib, "glew_static_x86_d.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "freeglut_static_x86_d.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "SOIL_static_x86_d.lib")
#else
#pragma comment(lib, "glew_static_x86.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "freeglut_static_x86.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "SOIL_static_x86.lib")
#endif

using namespace std;

//screen size
const int WIDTH  = 1280;
const int HEIGHT = 960;

//shader reference
GLSLShader shader;

//vertex array and vertex buffer object IDs
GLuint vaoID;
GLuint vboVerticesID;
GLuint vboIndicesID;

const int NUM_X = 40; //total quads on X axis
const int NUM_Z = 40; //total quads on Z axis

const float SIZE_X = 4; //size of plane in world space
const float SIZE_Z = 4;
const float HALF_SIZE_X = SIZE_X/2.0f;
const float HALF_SIZE_Z = SIZE_Z/2.0f;

//ripple displacement speed
const float SPEED = 2;

//ripple mesh vertices and indices
glm::vec3 vertices[(NUM_X+1)*(NUM_Z+1)];
const int TOTAL_INDICES = NUM_X*NUM_Z*2*3;
GLushort indices[TOTAL_INDICES];

//projection and modelview matrices
glm::mat4  P = glm::mat4(1);
glm::mat4 MV = glm::mat4(1);

//camera transformation variables
int state = 0, oldX=0, oldY=0;
float rX=25, rY=-40, dist = -7;

//current time
float time = 0;

//mouse click handler
void OnMouseDown(int button, int s, int x, int y)
{
if (s == GLUT_DOWN)
{
    oldX = x;
    oldY = y;
}

if(button == GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON)
    state = 0;
else
    state = 1;
}

//mosue move handler
void OnMouseMove(int x, int y)
{
if (state == 0)
    dist *= (1 + (y - oldY)/60.0f);
else
{
    rY += (x - oldX)/5.0f;
    rX += (y - oldY)/5.0f;
}
oldX = x;
oldY = y;

glutPostRedisplay();
}

//OpenGL initialization
void OnInit() {
//set the polygon mode to render lines
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

GL_CHECK_ERRORS
//load shader
shader.LoadFromFile(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "shaders/shader.vert");
shader.LoadFromFile(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "shaders/shader.frag");
//compile and link shader
shader.CreateAndLinkProgram();
shader.Use();
    //add shader attribute and uniforms
    shader.AddAttribute("vVertex");
    shader.AddUniform("MVP");
    shader.AddUniform("time");
shader.UnUse();

GL_CHECK_ERRORS

//setup plane geometry
//setup plane vertices
int count = 0;
int i=0, j=0;
for( j=0;j<=NUM_Z;j++) {
    for( i=0;i<=NUM_X;i++) {
        vertices[count++] = glm::vec3( ((float(i)/(NUM_X-1)) *2-1)* HALF_SIZE_X, 0, ((float(j)/(NUM_Z-1))*2-1)*HALF_SIZE_Z);
    }
}

//fill plane indices array
GLushort* id=&indices[0];
for (i = 0; i < NUM_Z; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < NUM_X; j++) {
        int i0 = i * (NUM_X+1) + j;
        int i1 = i0 + 1;
        int i2 = i0 + (NUM_X+1);
        int i3 = i2 + 1;
        if ((j+i)%2) {
            *id++ = i0; *id++ = i2; *id++ = i1;
            *id++ = i1; *id++ = i2; *id++ = i3;
        } else {
            *id++ = i0; *id++ = i2; *id++ = i3;
            *id++ = i0; *id++ = i3; *id++ = i1;
        }
    }
}

GL_CHECK_ERRORS

//setup plane vao and vbo stuff
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID);
glGenBuffers(1, &vboVerticesID);
glGenBuffers(1, &vboIndicesID);

glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

    glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVerticesID);
    //pass plane vertices to array buffer object
    glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GL_CHECK_ERRORS
    //enable vertex attrib array for position
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader["vVertex"]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(shader["vVertex"], 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,0,0);
    GL_CHECK_ERRORS
    //pass the plane indices to element array buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIndicesID);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GL_CHECK_ERRORS
          
 cout<<"Initialization successfull"<<endl;
}


//release all allocated resources
void OnShutdown() {
//Destroy shader
shader.DeleteShaderProgram();

//Destroy vao and vbo
glDeleteBuffers(1, &vboVerticesID);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &vboIndicesID);
glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vaoID);

cout<<"Shutdown successfull"<<endl;
}

//resize event handler
void OnResize(int w, int h) {
//set the viewport size
glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
//setup the projection matrix
P = glm::perspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)w/h, 1.f, 1000.f);
}

//idle event callback
void OnIdle() {
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

//display callback 
void OnRender() {
//get the elapse time
time = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME)/1000.0f * SPEED;

//clear the colour and depth buffers
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

//set teh camera viewing transformation
glm::mat4 T     = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f),glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, dist));
glm::mat4 Rx    = glm::rotate(T,  rX, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
glm::mat4 MV    = glm::rotate(Rx, rY, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
glm::mat4 MVP   = P*MV;

//bind the shader 
shader.Use();
    //set the shader uniforms
    glUniformMatrix4fv(shader("MVP"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(MVP));
    glUniform1f(shader("time"), time);
        //draw the mesh triangles
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, TOTAL_INDICES, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

//unbind the shader
shader.UnUse();

//swap front and back buffers to show the rendered result
glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
//freeglut initialization calls
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
glutInitContextVersion (3, 3);
glutInitContextFlags (GLUT_CORE_PROFILE | GLUT_DEBUG);
glutInitWindowSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
glutCreateWindow("Ripple deformer - OpenGL 3.3");
    
//glew initialization   
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

GLenum err = glewInit();
if (GLEW_OK != err) {
    cerr<<"Error: "<<glewGetErrorString(err)<<endl;
} else {
    if (GLEW_VERSION_3_3)
    {
        cout<<"Driver supports OpenGL 3.3\nDetails:"<<endl;
    }
}
err = glGetError(); //this is to ignore INVALID ENUM error 1282
GL_CHECK_ERRORS
            
//print information on screen
cout<<"\tUsing GLEW "<<glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION)<<endl;
cout<<"\tVendor: "<<glGetString (GL_VENDOR)<<endl;
cout<<"\tRenderer: "<<glGetString (GL_RENDERER)<<endl;
cout<<"\tVersion: "<<glGetString (GL_VERSION)<<endl;
cout<<"\tGLSL: "<<glGetString (GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)<<endl;

GL_CHECK_ERRORS

//opengl initialization
OnInit();

//callback hooks
glutCloseFunc(OnShutdown);
glutDisplayFunc(OnRender);
glutReshapeFunc(OnResize);
glutMouseFunc(OnMouseDown);
glutMotionFunc(OnMouseMove);
glutIdleFunc(OnIdle);

//main loop call
glutMainLoop();

return 0;
}
```

And finally the shader code:

#### GLSLShader.cpp

```
#include "GLSLShader.h"
#include <iostream>


GLSLShader::GLSLShader(void)
{
_totalShaders=0;
_shaders[VERTEX_SHADER]=0;
_shaders[FRAGMENT_SHADER]=0;
_shaders[GEOMETRY_SHADER]=0;
_attributeList.clear();
_uniformLocationList.clear();
}

GLSLShader::~GLSLShader(void)
{
_attributeList.clear(); 
_uniformLocationList.clear();
}

void GLSLShader::DeleteShaderProgram() {    
glDeleteProgram(_program);
}

void GLSLShader::LoadFromString(GLenum type, const string& source) {    
GLuint shader = glCreateShader (type);

const char * ptmp = source.c_str();
glShaderSource (shader, 1, &ptmp, NULL);

//check whether the shader loads fine
GLint status;
glCompileShader (shader);
glGetShaderiv (shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
if (status == GL_FALSE) {
    GLint infoLogLength;        
    glGetShaderiv (shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogLength);
    GLchar *infoLog= new GLchar[infoLogLength];
    glGetShaderInfoLog (shader, infoLogLength, NULL, infoLog);
    cerr<<"Compile log: "<<infoLog<<endl;
    delete [] infoLog;
}
_shaders[_totalShaders++]=shader;
}


void GLSLShader::CreateAndLinkProgram() {
_program = glCreateProgram ();
if (_shaders[VERTEX_SHADER] != 0) {
    glAttachShader (_program, _shaders[VERTEX_SHADER]);
}
if (_shaders[FRAGMENT_SHADER] != 0) {
    glAttachShader (_program, _shaders[FRAGMENT_SHADER]);
}
if (_shaders[GEOMETRY_SHADER] != 0) {
    glAttachShader (_program, _shaders[GEOMETRY_SHADER]);
}

//link and check whether the program links fine
GLint status;
glLinkProgram (_program);
glGetProgramiv (_program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
if (status == GL_FALSE) {
    GLint infoLogLength;
    
    glGetProgramiv (_program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogLength);
    GLchar *infoLog= new GLchar[infoLogLength];
    glGetProgramInfoLog (_program, infoLogLength, NULL, infoLog);
    cerr<<"Link log: "<<infoLog<<endl;
    delete [] infoLog;
}

glDeleteShader(_shaders[VERTEX_SHADER]);
glDeleteShader(_shaders[FRAGMENT_SHADER]);
glDeleteShader(_shaders[GEOMETRY_SHADER]);
}

void GLSLShader::Use() {
glUseProgram(_program);
}

void GLSLShader::UnUse() {
glUseProgram(0);
}

void GLSLShader::AddAttribute(const string& attribute) {
_attributeList[attribute]= glGetAttribLocation(_program, attribute.c_str());    
}

//An indexer that returns the location of the attribute
GLuint GLSLShader::operator [](const string& attribute) {
return _attributeList[attribute];
}

void GLSLShader::AddUniform(const string& uniform) {
_uniformLocationList[uniform] = glGetUniformLocation(_program, uniform.c_str());
}

GLuint GLSLShader::operator()(const string& uniform){
return _uniformLocationList[uniform];
}

#include <fstream>
void GLSLShader::LoadFromFile(GLenum whichShader, const string& filename){
ifstream fp;
fp.open(filename.c_str(), ios_base::in);
if(fp) {         
    string line, buffer;
    while(getline(fp, line)) {
        buffer.append(line);
        buffer.append("\r\n");
    }        
    //copy to source
    LoadFromString(whichShader, buffer);        
} else {
    cerr<<"Error loading shader: "<<filename<<endl;
}
}
```

#### Debug 1 [**RESOLVED**]

Ahh, so I did what @KimKulling suggested and made the variable into `elapsedTime` instead of just `time`. So the file does compile to an executable `mycc`, but when I run it I get the following error:

```
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-version.c: 224: _dl_check_map_versions: Assertion `needed != ((void *)0)' failed!
```

The line that it points to: 224 is just the first line of the main function `int main() . . .`.

I worked on it some more and discovered this issue has to do with an existing bug associated with dynamic library inconsistencies with OpenGL/C++. There is an existing bug filed on this issue.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-319/+bug/1248642

The good news is that someone found a workaround.

[error running a compiled C++ file (uses OpenGL). Error: “Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-version.c: 224”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007961/error-running-a-compiled-c-file-uses-opengl-error-inconsistency-detected)

All I had to do was use different compile settings. It was really not intuitive.

I had to add a directory link to the video driver. Here is what worked:

```
 g++ -L/usr/lib/nvidia-340/ main.cpp GLSLShader.cpp -lglut -lGLEW -lGL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler seems to be right. There is already a symbol named time, so you have to change the name for something like

```
float elapsedTime = 0.0f;
```

When other errors occurres afterwards you have to fix them as well of course. But I thing the reason for them are a little bit different, so try to investigate the reasons and fix them step by step.

Maybe posting the next error could be a beginning :-).

Comment: Yes thanks for your help on this. I did change the name of the `time` variable and then got a different error--which I posted above. Seems like the new error I got is associated with some existing OpenGL/C++ bug about linking dynamic libraries. So I updated the compiler settings and it worked. Thanks for your help.